# Formulating a specific custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, keras

[image]

I am trying to formulate a custom loss function as above, based on **3 output variables**. Essentially, i want to normalize the error of each output given as abs(y_true - y_pred) by taking the maximum of either y_true or y_pred, and then sum it up for the combined loss.

**What I've tried so far**

```
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    
    y_true_fc = K.cast(y_true_f, 'float32')
    y_pred_fc = K.cast(y_pred_f, 'float32')

    err = K.abs(y_true_fc - y_pred_fc)

    loss = K.sum(err)
    return loss
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'reduction_indices' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

I am not sure if I need flatten() or the K.cast(), but it seems to be a standard flow based on my searches in SO. How I should proceed from here in order to get the max values for denominator and finally, the combined loss? I don't think I've written the code correctly to reflect the equation.

Also, does the above formulation perform the computation for each sample in each batch?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace. Which call causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because [K.max](https://keras.io/backend/#max) computes the maximum value along a *single* tensor (the second argument indicates the reduction axes). To find the element-wise maximum between *two tensors*, you may use [K.maximum](https://keras.io/backend/#maximum) instead. The following function implements your equation:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_c = K.cast(y_true, 'float32')  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
    y_pred_c = K.cast(y_pred, 'float32')  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)

    # Compute error
    num = K.abs(y_true_c - y_pred_c)  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
    den = K.maximum(y_true_c, y_pred_c)   # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
    err = K.sum(num / den, axis=-1)  # Shape=(batch_size,)

    # Output loss
    return K.mean(err)
```

It might not be necessary to cast your inputs. Note that instead of flattening the inputs, I am computing the average loss (it is a common practice to compute the mean to aggregate all the individual losses).

**NOTE:** Not tested.

Comment: appreciate your proposed solution, I have run it and it was error-free. Just curious, what does the axis=-1 do?

Comment: strange im ending up with NaN losses for some of the iterations

Comment: I use `axis=-1` to compute the sum over the last axis (your sum_{i=1,2,3} for each element in the batch). What is the domain of `y_true` and `y_pred`? For the equation that you provided, you would get a NaN when the denominator is 0 (i.e.  when y_true_i=y_pred_i=0 for any i)

Comment: i see, what might be the best way to avoid the NaN result during the run? maybe input a very small value?

Comment: You could sum a small epsilon (i.e. `1e-7`) to `den`. In this way, when y_true_i=y_pred_i=0 the loss for this term is 0.

Comment: for this implementation, is there a way to weigh the losses, instead of averaging?

Comment: also in my model.compile() function, i input loss_weights=[0.25,0.5,0.25]. Does this actually do anything in the custom loss function?

Comment: If you have 3 loss functions, this sets the weight of each loss in the combined loss

Comment: I currently have only a single loss function which is the one stated in your solution. In this case, does it mean that the loss weights is a redundant parameter, since only 1 loss is used?

Comment: what i want to do is to assign different loss weight to each of the 3 output variables. How can i achieve this in the current formulation?

Comment: You can wrap your loss function in another function having the 3-weight vector as a parameter. I'll be happy to provide an example in another question!

Comment: ok i have asked another question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627054/regarding-weighting-on-an-3-output-ann-with-custom-loss