# Regarding weighting on an 3-output ANN with custom loss

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to define a custom loss function which takes in 3 output variables in a regression model.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_c = K.cast(y_true, 'float32')  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
    y_pred_c = K.cast(y_pred, 'float32')  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)

    # Compute error
    num = K.abs(y_true_c - y_pred_c)  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
    den = K.maximum(y_true_c, y_pred_c)   # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
    err = K.sum(num / den, axis=-1)  # Shape=(batch_size,)

    # Output loss
    return K.mean(err)
```

How can I weigh the 3 losses given by the 3 outputs, prior to its summation to a single loss value?

My model.compile() statement is currently:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, metrics=['mse'],optimizer=optimizer, loss_weights=[0.25,0.5,0.25])
```

where I am trying to weigh them 0.25, 0.5, 0.25 (sums up to 1) for each of the 3 outputs respectively. However I think this implement may not work with the custom loss function.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass an extra argument `weights` to your custom loss as follows:

```
def custom_loss(weights):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true_c = K.cast(y_true, 'float32')  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
        y_pred_c = K.cast(y_pred, 'float32')  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)

        # Compute error
        num = K.abs(y_true_c - y_pred_c)  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
        den = K.maximum(y_true_c, y_pred_c)  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
        aux = weights * (num / den)  # Shape=(batch_size, 3)
        err = K.sum(aux, axis=-1)  # Shape=(batch_size,)

        # Output loss
        return K.mean(err)

    return loss
```

And then compile your model as shown below:

```
# weights shape is (3,)
weights = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.25])
model.compile(loss=custom_loss(weights), metrics=['mse'], optimizer=optimizer)
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.